# window.open lost focus in chrome and IE7

Tags: javascript, events

I am using google map in my site i added some user define icon on the map , if user click on the icon it redirect to 
corresponding site using window.open (js). it work fine in mozila but in google chrome window.open open the page in seperate tab but newly opened window is not
an active window . It lost focus,it automatically moved focus to its parent window . i am usin below code

```
PortsMarkerArray.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', redirectToTravels);

function redirectToTravels(){

    //alert(this.getTitle());

    var att_name = this.getTitle();
    var county = getCookie('county'); 
    //alert(county);
     for(var j=0;j<attractions.length;j++){

        if(attractions[j][2] == att_name){
                var link = attractions[j][6];

                window.open(link,'_newtab');



                setattractionToReport(county,att_name);

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this code , now my issue resolved

```
setTimeout(function () { 
var newwindow = window.open(link,'_blank');
```

> newwindow.focus(); },     0.5);
>
> return false;

Answer (score 0):

window.open() returns a handler for the opened window object. Try the following code:

```
var newWin = window.open(link,'_newtab');
newWin.focus();
```